# Sphinx showing attributes twice

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I'm trying to write an API documentation using sphinx
I've started from models but can't get attributes documented properly.

Here is an example:

```py
class Incoterm(AuditedModel(updatable=True), ModelBase, db.Model):
    """Incoterm Definition

    Args:
        AuditedModel (class): Audit class
        ModelBase (class): Model base class
        db (class): SQLAlchemy instance

    Attributes:
        abbreviation (String): an abbreviation
        full_name (String): the full name
        group (String): which group it belong

    """

    abbreviation = Column(String(3), nullable=False)
    full_name = Column(String(128), nullable=False)
    group = Column(String(1), nullable=False)
```

using `$ sphinx-apidoc -o . ..` and `$ make html` the docs generated shows the *Attributes* twice and class inheritance without their definitions.

I also tried to insert a comment right before the variable like `#: str: an string` as described in [sphinx examples](https://sphinxcontrib-napoleon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example_google.html) but got the same result...

One work around i found was comment `:undoc-members:` at the .rst file.
There is a better way to achieve this? What am i missing?

[image]

Comment: This question lacks details, it does not show the `.rst` files and neither does it show the `conf.py` options. Meaning it does not have a [*"Minimal, Reproducible, Example."*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you document class attributes like this, the problem is likely to go away.

```
class Incoterm(AuditedModel(updatable=True), ModelBase, db.Model):
    """Incoterm Definition

    Args:
        AuditedModel (class): Audit class
        ModelBase (class): Model base class
        db (class): SQLAlchemy instance
    """

    abbreviation = Column(String(3), nullable=False)
    """an abbreviation"""

    full_name = Column(String(128), nullable=False)
    """the full name"""

    group = Column(String(1), nullable=False)
    """which group it belong"""
```

Reference:
https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#directive-autoattribute
scroll down to `class Foo` example.